# how to remove iOS app meta data (like push notifications badge, use widget flag, ..)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, caching

I didn't find a similar question or useful info on this topic.

I just want to remove my app from iPhone and get a completely fresh version with no caching nor meta caching...

examples of meta caching

```
1- Push notification badge.
2- Apple App Site Association.  
3- whether to show the app widget or not.
```

When I delete the app and install it again, the push notifications badge **still shows '1'**, and the app widget get's added automatically.

so there's metadata stored on the iPhone for my app, ... where is it? and how to reset it?

I can reset the simulator of iOS and get a clean build 100%, but this won't help because what I need is a fresh version of the Apple-App-Site-Association file, this is only testable on the iOS device, and not testable on the simulator.

I tried to delete files using [iExplorer](http://iexplorer.en.lo4d.com/) mac app, no clue there.

any hints?

Comment: have you tried to change the bundle ID of the app?

Comment: it will work for simple cases, but not all cases, won't help when there is apple-app-site-association in the app.